# grid view using twitter bootstrap columns has some empty columns in a row

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create a grid view in my site, a 4x10 columns as you can see [here](http://www.directory.shopious.com/Wanita/Atasan%20&%20Bawahan/). The issue is that there is a row where the columns are not fully filled, as can be seen on this screenshot:

[image]

Any idea what might be causing this? I tried debugging this using inspector and can't see the reason why.

Comment: any code...html css???

Comment: it looks perfectly fine on mozilla.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the height of 4th element in First row. Increase its height and your issue will resolve.

[image]